# What is slowing down my application response?

Tags: java, performance, threadpool

My application response is slow. To investigate I took a thread-dump using jvisualvm which shows lot of threads are waiting on same condition but none of them leading to code  that I have written i.e. none of the java classes are mine, they all belong to JDK. Should I use some other tool to get thread-dump.
[Thread Dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b6Mv0Q3uC3F1nVNKtu1JWJRc4rbxsZaB/view?usp=sharing)

```
Line 85: - parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
Line 103:- parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
Line 121:- parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
Line 139:- parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
Line 157:- parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
Line 175:- parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
Line 778:- parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
Line 796:- parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
Line 814:- parking to wait for  <0x000000070208c8d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
```

Comment: The threads you have identified are worker threads in a ThreadPoolExecutor.  They are all waiting for work to do. The thread names imply that these are Tomcat request workers.  That is normal ... for an idle server.   I would look to see if there is something interfering with network traffic to your server.

Comment: For performance issues, you should do profiling (find out which part/operation is taking what time). You provided no information what could help to reliable answer your question.

Comment: @gusto2, what profiler to use? It must be freeware, and it is prod, so no ide? Will visualvm do? And what to profile? Cpu ? Memory?